# Empty range for randrange() error (0, 0, 0)

Tags: python

Code:

```
import random
s=['Svetlana Zueva', 'Arkady Belykh', 'Boris Bokov']  # list first/last name
proof=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    timemas=list(s) # a list in which there is no s[i] element(student), so that there are no repetitions when the student is a friend of himself
    del timemas[i]
    while 1!=2: # endless loop until we find a friend
        a=timemas[random.randint(0,len(timemas)-1)] # when we have 2 elements(a sequence from 0 to 2) - they are written as 0 1(2 does not count), the randint method includes 2 and it turns out 3 elements instead of 2. (a friend is here)
        if a not in proof: # checking if a friend repeats
            print(s[i],'-',a)
            proof.append(a)
            break
```

Please tell me, sometimes an error pops up at startup:

```
empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)
```

It occurs when `randrange` reads an empty list (probably).

I can't understand where it comes from, I ran it through the visualizer - everything is OK, an error sometimes comes out through the paycharm.

An empty list cannot be taken like this, because only 1 element is deleted, and then, when the `for` cycle starts anew, the initial list appears and 1 element is also deleted from it (the list always changes only by 1 element, not by all).

Condition:

> The program randomly assigns each student his secret friend who will solve programming tasks with him, you also can't be a secret friend to yourself and you can't be a secret friend to several students.

Output data (there may be other options):

```
Svetlana Zueva - Boris Bokov
Arkady Belykh - Svetlana Zueva
Boris Bokov - Arkady Belykh
```

Comment: Your current code excludes the last item of the list from the random choice, so it fails when the list only has one element.  Either use `randrange()` instead of `randint()`, or get rid of that `- 1` in the range.